# Generating an OAuth 2.0 access token for a service account returning permission denied error

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-admin-sdk, service-accounts

I wanted to use the rest API [https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/{name=projects/*/serviceAccounts/*}:generateAccessToken](https://iamcredentials.googleapis.com/v1/%7Bname=projects/*/serviceAccounts/*%7D:generateAccessToken) to get the access token by the serviceaccount email but I am getting error even though I created a custom role with a permission iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken and granted it to the service account email but I keep getting the error below on the google API explorer :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "domain": "iam.googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "permission": "iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken"
        }
      }
    ]
```

}
}

[image]

What did I miss ?